# Valgrind Use of unitialized value and Invalid read

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, valgrind

I'm trying to read a text file with different lines into an array. The array is called `fileArr` that is an array of pointers, each index point to a `lineArr` string of characters.

Opening the file and checking the file length work. But when I get to reading the file into an array, it gives a problem. Here's my code:

```
int main()
{   
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);   // seek to end of file
    int fileLen = ftell(file);  // get current file pointer
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);   // seek back to beginning of file
    printf("file length = %d\n", fileLen);

    char **fileArr = malloc(sizeof(char*) * fileLen);
    char *lineArr = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char*) * (MAX_LINE_LEN + 1));
    int i = 0;

    while(1) {
        fileArr[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (MAX_LINE_LEN + 1)); //This is line 73

        // Read from the file
        if(fgets(lineArr, MAX_LINE_LEN, file) != NULL)  {
            // Check if line is too long
            if(strlen(lineArr) > MAX_LINE_LEN) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Line too long");
                exit(1);  // exit with return code 1
            }
            // If not, write content in one line to array
            strcpy(fileArr[i], lineArr);  
        }
        else {  // If reach to the end of file
            // Free the fileArr at index i
            free(fileArr[i]);
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    // Then print out the array
    printLines(fileArr, fileLen); // This is line 91

    // Free memory
    free(lineArr);
    free(fileArr);
    return 0;
}

/** Method to print out array **/
void printLines (char *ptArray[], size_t count)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", ptArray[i]); // This is line 100 
    }
}
```

The file is printed out, but there's a Segmentation fault error. And then valgrind prints out this huge terrifying message (the name of the file containing this code is textsort.c):

```
==13032== Invalid read of size 1
==13032==    at 0x4C30F62: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==13032==    by 0x4EA969B: puts (ioputs.c:35)
==13032==    by 0x400DB0: printLines (textsort3.c:100)
==13032==    by 0x400D54: main (textsort3.c:91)
==13032==  Address 0x5207180 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1,032 free'd
==13032==    at 0x4C2EDEB: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==13032==    by 0x400D28: main (textsort3.c:83)
==13032==  Block was alloc'd at
==13032==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==13032==    by 0x400C88: main (textsort3.c:73)
==13032== 

==13032== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==13032==    at 0x4C30F62: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==13032==    by 0x4EA969B: puts (ioputs.c:35)
==13032==    by 0x400DB0: printLines (textsort3.c:100)
==13032==    by 0x400D54: main (textsort3.c:91)
==13032== 
==13032== 
==13032== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==13032==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==13032==    at 0x4C30F62: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==13032==    by 0x4EA969B: puts (ioputs.c:35)
==13032==    by 0x400DB0: printLines (textsort3.c:100)
==13032==    by 0x400D54: main (textsort3.c:91)
==13032==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==13032==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==13032==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==13032==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==13032==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==13032== 
==13032== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13032==     in use at exit: 6,304 bytes in 6 blocks
==13032==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 4 frees, 13,008 bytes allocated
==13032== 
==13032== LEAK SUMMARY:
==13032==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13032==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13032==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13032==    still reachable: 6,304 bytes in 6 blocks
==13032==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13032== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==13032== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==13032== 
==13032== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==13032== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==13032== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What is its problem? Do you have any suggestions? I appreciate all your help!

Comment: To avoid `lineArr = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char*)...` size error, When allocating, use `lineArr = malloc(sizeof *lineArr * n);`  This error is making the allocation too big, but does not cause seg fault.

Comment: `printLines(fileArr, fileLen);` --> `printLines(fileArr, i);`  I think this is the seg fault error

Comment: Where and how does `fileLen` get set?

Comment: @chux You're right! But I know the `printLines` function is good because you helped me with it yesterday :) XOXO

Comment: @alk That is a great question. I think that's where it went wrong. I added some code at the beginning to show you how `fileLen` was set!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few problems and suggestions:-

- Here in the `printLines` function you are always printing until the index reaches `fileLen`. Now if `fileLen` is not equal to `i` or something higher than that - it will try to access an uninitialized value and passing them to `printf` would be undefined behavior. <sup>(chux comment and alk comment)</sup>
- Also another thing - your check of string length being greater than `MAX_LINE_LEN` is wrong. You can never deduce that "Line is too Long" from this. Read `fgets` return value to get the desired behavior. (It reads `MAX_LINE_LEN-1` characters and the last position contains `\0`. So one way you can be sure that a complete line is being read is by finding the `\n` - if it is there then a complete line is being read).

  Also when `fgets` returns `NULL` you are freeing them but then again you don't set it to `NULL` so that when you print you can selective print the valid ones (Not the ones which are having `NULL`). You have to consider this too. Whether return from `fgets` is due to error condition or not - will be checked by using `feof()` and `ferror()`. In case you are using `POSIX` one then `fgets` sets the `errno` if it encounters some failure other than the end of file condition. Check the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to get more idea.
- Amount of memory that you allocate is larger than you need in this case - but the way you do using wrong `type` would create problem.  `char *lineArr = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char*) * (MAX_LINE_LEN + 1));` you are allocating space for `MAX_LINE_LEN+1` `char*`-s it should be `char`-s. That is what you want to store in the memory pointed by `lineArr`. Same would be the case with other allocation in `fileArr[i]`.

  After correction (Note that the cast is removed, that conversion is implicit)<sup>`sizeof` `char` is `1` always. So we can do it as shown in comment too.</sup>

  ```
  char *lineArr =  malloc(sizeof(char) * (MAX_LINE_LEN + 1));//malloc(MAX_LINE_LEN + 1)
  ...
  fileArr[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (MAX_LINE_LEN + 1));
  ```

Comment: @alk.: Ah it's a problem which is not causing problem here....reading the code and seeing a coment here and after trying to find incomplete code posted - it seems `printLines` is a source of problem too (if not the earlier0

Comment: OT: `sizeof (char)` equals `1` by definition.

Comment: @alk.: Yes know that - will make an edit mentioning chux and your comment.

Comment: "*Also when `fgets` fails ...*" the code never checks if `fgets()` failed. To test for failure testing for `NULL`  is not sufficient, as it also can mean end-of-file reached. It needs to be followed by a call to `ferror()`.

Answer (score 1):

Since lineArr is a array of characters and not array of strings, it should be given sizeof(char) as parameter rather than sizeof(char*)

Below is the working version of code that you posted. I've replaced malloc with calloc (personal preference, otherwise both are fine). And replaced while(1) with while(fgets(lineArr, MAX_LINE_LEN, file)) so that the loop ends right after file ends.

```
char **fileArr = (char**)calloc(sizeof(char*), fileLen);
char *lineArr = (char *)calloc(sizeof(char), (MAX_LINE_LEN + 1));
int i = 0;


while (fgets(lineArr, MAX_LINE_LEN, file))
{
    fileArr[i] = (char*)calloc(sizeof(char), (MAX_LINE_LEN + 1)); //This is line 73

    if (strlen(lineArr) > MAX_LINE_LEN)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Line too long");
        exit(1);
    }

    strcpy(fileArr[i], lineArr);
    i++;
}

printLines(fileArr, fileLen); 

free(lineArr);
free(fileArr);

getch();
return 0;
```

Comment: Please accept one of the answers if your issue is resolved.

Comment: "*Below is the working version of code that you posted*" how would you know size, without knowing the rest of the OP's code?

Comment: OT: no need to cast `calloc()`.

Comment: @Shrey That code structure looks sooo much better than the original. I changed it like you suggested. Thank you!